# How do I set password and AES 256 for external HDD?

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, password, encryption, hdd

I want to set a password and AES(128/256) encryption for my external HDD so one has to enter a password to gain access.

How can I do this?

I’m asking because I don’t see such an option in Disk Utility in the **Erase** menu. I can only see AES in **File** > **New image** > **Image from HDD**, but this is only for files or folders or making big images, but not for setting passwords for the HDD.